# Alternative to git lfs

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

Not sure if this is the right place to ask but I have the following question.

Basically I published a git repo where there are large files (30 and 150 mb) and I have been uploading those with git lfs.
However, when somebody downloads/clone the repo that is counted against my git lfs amount (1gb) and basically drained it. Are there any alternatives? I do not need to modify those files anymore once they were uploaded, is just insane having to purchase a data package when I am not actively using lfs anymore.

Comment: What do you mean by "counted against my git lfs amount"? Git doesn't have any inherent limits to the amount of data that can be downloaded from its repos. Are you talking about GitHub?

Comment: I mean anybody who clones the repo does not get all the files, thereby the software cannot be used. I received an email saying that my lfs quote has been reached for this month

Comment: git doesn't have quotas, nor can it send emails. Sounds like a feature of whatever service provider you're using to host your published repo. Again, are you using GitHub? Who is sending you these emails?

Comment: yup GitHub my bad

Comment: Here's the GitHub quota documentation: https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/about-storage-and-bandwidth-usage

Comment: You could rewrite the repo history to remove your dependency on LFS, but the 150MB file will cause you to hit the max file size for GitHub.

Comment: Ok so by using GitHub there is no way to not use LSF for large files